# Datasource and transaction manager scope in Spring?

Tags: spring

In a spring application what should be the scope of datasource and transaction manager?As per my understanding
both should be singleton. Is that correct?

Comment: This is your 23rd question in the last 2 weeks, and you've accepted answers to only 3 of them.  Please accept answers to the rest, before asking more.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely. Those aren't the kinds of objects that should have more than one floating around.